# Multiple diode circuit homework problem

Tags: current, diodes, zener

Can you show a step by step explanation as to how to find the current in each resistor?
my attempt :

I1 = (18V(input voltage ) - 7.5V(Zener voltage)) / 5k(resistance)

I2 = (18V(input voltage ) - 24V(Zener voltage)) / 2k(resistance)

[image]

Comment: First of all is this homework for a class? Normally we only give hints to homework problems, and ask that the questioner show some effort before giving an answer. Second, have you learned Ohm's law for resistors? V = I x R?

Comment: Also, do you know what D1 and D2 are, and how they behave?

Comment: That's an interesting one. Please show, what you have already done, what your thoughts are and where you're stuck. I assume the diodes can be considered ideal diodes. This problem takes a little bit of trial end error and some tinkering, but it's definitely solvable with knowing how zeners work and ohms law (and kirchhoff)

Comment: id like any references to how to understand the concept, cause based on my class as far as ive leant. I= (Vcc-Vdd)/R. Butim not clear if its the equivalent resistance or the resistance of each resistor

Comment: @ttomtt Looks a lot like [this recently posted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/607741/38098).

Comment: "*I do not understand how to solve this as I am new to electronics*" isn't a good title for your question as doesn't tell  us what it's about. I've modified it to a more descriptive title. 'V' for volt and 'Zener' is Mr. Zener's surname so it gets a capital.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to say anything different than what it has already been presented, but I hope in a more simple way to be easier to understand.
Here is your circuit as I understand:

[image]

First break it down into two branches:

[image]

Do the math: + 18V – I1*R1 – 7.5V – 5V = 0

[image]

Do the math: + 18V – I1*R1 – 7.5V – I2*R2 – (-24V) = 0

When you calculate the two currents and determine the voltage at node Va you will find out that the node has a voltage of -19.5V from I1 and -14.2V from I2. That is not possible, so diode D2 must be forward biased dropping 0.7 V.

[image]

Break down into two branches again:

[image]

Do the math: + 18V – I1*R1 – 7.5V - (-0.7V) = 0

[image]

Do the math: -0.7V – I2*R2 – (-24V) = 0

Because the I2 current includes the I1 current, the current in the diode from ground to the -24V voltage source is  I2 – I1.

[image]

Comment: "Va = -19.5V Not possible so Va = 0.7V". Shouldn't that be -0.7V?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, you are right. I have edited the answer showing the correct sign of the diode D2 voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

Below I added a bunch of information to the diagram to make it easier to talk about the circuit.

I renamed -VDD as V3 because otherwise it is too confusing with the minus sign.

VCC is given. R1 is given. R2 is given. V3 is given.

The three lines below D2 are the special symbol for ground (GND). That is always defined as 0 volts.

The problems says:

> Vz1 = 7.5 V

What this means is that V1 - V2 = 7.5 V.

Likewise it says Vz2 is 5 V. So that means V2 - 0 = 5 V.

So now, you can figure out i2:

i2 = (V2 - V3) / 2k

But V2 and V3 are basically given. Do you see that? Let me know if any part of this confuses you.

[image]

Comment: You should probably assume that the forward voltage of D2 is 0.6V.

Comment: Hmmmm. @GTElectronics I doubt that is what was intended when the question was posed, but you may be right. Without actually working it out, it is obvious now that you mention it that I2 is going to be way larger than I1, therefore D2 will be forward biased.

Comment: To the OP, based on what GT electronics pointed out, you may have to assume that V2 - 0 = 0.6 V instead of V2 - 0 = 5 V. That is more reasonable. You can still solve for I2, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you show a step by step explanation as to how to find the current in each resistor?

[image]

**Forget for a short time, R2.**
Calculate the current through R1: \$(18-7.5-5)/5k= ~ 1.1 mA \$.
D1 and D2 are ***on*** (Zener effect).
The voltage on D2 seems being thus \$ 5 V \$.

Then, **we include R2**, there ***should*** be a current (in R2) of \$(5-(-24))/2k= ~ 14.5 mA\$.

As \$ (14.5 mA >> 1.1 mA) \$, this lead to think that D2 will be on (but with simple diode effect), thus \$V(D2)= ~ -0.7 V \$ .
So, we correct : \$I2 = (-0.7-(-24))/2k = 11.65 mA \$,
and \$I1= (18-(-0.7)-7.5) / 5k = ~ 2.24 mA\$ ...
And \$I(D2)= ~ (11.65 mA - 2.24 mA) = 9.41 mA \$ (as simple diode).